# changing entity schema name before sessionFactory inicialization

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

During migration from hibernate 3 version to 4 version I faced with problem.
I use spring and hibernate in my project and during start up of my application sometimes I want to change schema of my entity classes. With 3 version hibernate and spring I make this by overriding postProcessConfiguration method in LocalSessionFactortBean class like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void postProcessAnnotationConfiguration(AnnotationConfiguration config)
    {
        Iterator<Table> it = config.getTableMappings();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            Table table = it.next();
            table.setSchema(schemaConfigurator.getSchemaName(table.getSchema()));
        }
    }
```

this work perfect for me. But in hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean class all post process methods were deleted. Some people suggest to use  `ServiceRegistryBuilder` class, but I want to use spring xml configuration for my session factory and with `ServiceRegistryBuilder` class I don't know how to perform this. So may be someone suggest any solution to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at source code help to find solution. `LocalSessionFactoryBean` class has method called `buildSessionFactory`(`newSessionFactory` in previous version). With previous version of `Hibernate`(3 version) some operations where processed before this method call. You can see them in official docs

```
        // Tell Hibernate to eagerly compile the mappings that we registered,
        // for availability of the mapping information in further processing.
        postProcessMappings(config);
        config.buildMappings();
```

as I understand (may be I'm wrong) this `buildMapping` method parses all classes that specified as mapped classes or placed in `packagesToScan` and creates Table representation of all this classes. After this called `postProcessConfiguration` method.

With `Hibernate` 4 version we don't have such postProcess methods. But we can override `buildSessionFactory` method like this:

```
@Override
protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sfb) {
    sfb.buildMappings();
    // For my task we need this
    Iterator<Table> iterator = getConfiguration().getTableMappings();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        Table table = iterator.next();
        if(table.getSchema() != null && !table.getSchema().isEmpty()){
            table.setSchema(schemaConfigurator.getSchemaName(table.getSchema()));
        }
    }
    return super.buildSessionFactory(sfb);
}
```